# Swap not possible, default gas extremely high

Tags: gas, sushiswap

EDIT : Problem solve, 10% slippage via Metamask swap

I haven't been able to swap for several hours on Arbitrium. Initially going through the ShushiSwap interface which cannot estimate the gas then not Metamask which displays "JSON-RPC error". So I tried to go directly through the contract on Arbiscan, but the Metamask shows me huge gas costs. I tried to reduce the gas limit and validate the transaction but it fails. Do you have any ideas where the probleme come from ?

I've made lot of research, try many things and i don't find solution.

Thank you,
[image]
[image]

---

I use https://eth-converter.com/.
3000 ARD for 0.035 ETH when i tried.
The converteur give me 3000000000000000000000 and 35000000000000000. I tried different amount.

What do you mean by trying Web3 ? It's a protocol ?

I deleted the [], nothing change.

It's a shitcoin $ARD.

Already approve it.

AmountOut try put 0 doesn't work either

Function SupportinFeesOnSwap doesn't work.

[image]

I don't understand why the gas limit is out of tolerance by default. I have the impression that it is the wallet that is lacking.
Since it's on Arbitrium, I can't go through Ledger Live and I have to go through Metamask.

I tried to reset it and from other devices but the problem remains the same.

Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you good ether to **wei convertion** ? (**decimal of token** you swapping)

Do you try with **web3** ? maybe error on network

Or delete **[]** in path ?

What **tokens** are you **trying** to swap ?
(contract address)

**Approve** token before swap it ?

**AmountOut** try put **0** ?

Maybe need **add tolerance** ?

Try swap function with **SupportinFeesOnSwap**

Comment: provide the contract address please or decimals or approve it before swap or try put 0 in amountOut

Comment: Web3 is coding your creat a files an swap with code like JavaScript or Python,

Comment: Finally did it by Metamask with 10% slippage. I had already turned up the slip to 10% on Sushi it didn't work